# Getting the length of a list when it has one element

Tags: python

I have a list that only contains one string element. If I use

```
len(list)
```

it will return the amount of characters instead of the value 1. How can I make it to return the value 1?

Comment: "it will return the amount of characters instead of the value 1." - No. It'll return the size of the list.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the entire code, since what you're describing is **not** the behavior of python. If you do len([ "test" ]) you'll get 1.

Comment: i suspect that in your case `list` is actually a string. If you provide code it will help you get an answer

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to use the word list as variable name because the function list exists.

```
list_ = 'blah',
len(list_)
# returns 1
```

or

```
string_ = 'blah'
len([string_,])
# returns 1
```

Comment: this is very clever, but I'm not sure its helpful for the OP, who says 'I have a list that only contains one string element.' when likely he has a single string that he has called `list`

Answer (score 0):

The len() function should work because it is used to find the length of the list, array or tuple. I think your are using a char list maybe that’s why it is returning the number of character. Can you post your full code here.
If the len() function is not working then you can also use the loop like:

```
Int counter=0
for i in list:
     counter=counter+1
Print(Counter)
```

Comment: We don't use `int variable` or `variable++` in python...

Answer (score 0):

It actually matters how do you define your list variable.
I second @qräbnö. Since 'list' is a keyword in python, you should not use it as a variable literal.

If you have defined list variable as below, it will always return length of your string. Please note - It is not  list, but indeed a string with variable name 'list'.

```
>>> list = 'hello'
>>> len(list)
5
```

Good way to define your list as below. Assuming it has the same one element as you mistakenly defined above as string -

```
>>> list = ['hello']
>>> len(list)
1
```